# How can I get the elements without a particular attribute using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I know how to get elements with a particular *attribute*:

```
$("#para [attr_all]")
```

But how can I get the elements WITHOUT a particular attribute?

I tried:

```
 $("#para :not([attr_all])")
```

but it didn't work. What is the correct way to do this?

---

Let me give an example:

HTML:

```html
<div id="para">
    <input name="fname" optional="1">
    <input name="lname">
    <input name="email">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```js
$("#para [optional]")       // give me the fname element  
$("#para :not([optional])") // give me the fname, lname, email (fname should not appear here)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First thing that comes to my mind (maybe sub optimal) :

```
$('p').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).attr('attr_all');
});
```

However `p:not([attr_all])` should work, so I think something else is going on in your code.

Comment: I finally solved the problem and it was caused by another part of code and so I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 127):

If your code example is the exact code you're using, I think the problem is an errant space.

```
$("#para :not([attr_all])")
```

should be

```
$("#para:not([attr_all])")
```

If you leave a space in there, it selects *descendants* of `#para`.

Comment: But, from the original question, the OP **wants** to select the descendants!

Comment: Maybe use `*`, for me I cannot leave spaces.

Answer (score 7):

A faster way to do this is to first get all the elements with the ID para (which is invalid HTML if there is more than one, consider using a class instead) and use the filter (or find depending on how the HTML is constructed) method to only get the elements without the attribute like so:

```
$('#para').filter(':not([attr_all])');
```

Doing this you are having jQuery do much less work because you are only looping through a smaller subset of elements to get those without the attribute.  Doing it with a single selector statement, eg `$("#para :not([attr_all])")`, will cause jQuery to get all elements without the attribute, then filter them for ones with the ID of para.

Answer (score 6):

Try [`$("#para [attr!=val]")`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeNotEqual#attributevalue).

Your `:not` really should work, though, which makes me suspect something else is going on.

For a full list of attribute selectors, see the [jQuery Selectors docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Comment: Yeah, I think your problem is in the context, not this selector.

Comment: +1. Do note that this selector is JQuery-specific. It's not defined as a CSS attribute selector, so it can not be used to target elements for styling (via CSS): http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors

Answer (score 1):

Frank DeRosa's answer is about right, but since the OP does want to find the descendants, it's a bit off. Trying it myself, it seems like it should be working the way it is, but it's possible that whatever you're running doesn't like the ':' operator being used directly as a descendant. Try using

```
$("#para input:not([optional])")
```

Would have left a comment but can't yet.

Comment: Or perhaps a more broad selector: `$("#para *:not([optional])")`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at CSS3 selectors documentation the correct to select a node “node” without an attribute “attr” is:

```
<node>:not(<node>[<attr>])

E.g.: p:not(p[align])
```

In your case `$("#para *:not([optional])")` works, and could be more precise.

The actual syntax of "**:not**" is:

```
<selector1>:not(<selector2>)
```

There are **two** selectors in this expression, which selects all the nodes matching *seletor1* then excludes all nodes matching *selector2*.

I would use:

```
$('#para input:not(input[optional])')

    /* or */

$('input:not(input[optional])',$('#para'))

    /* in case jQuery has issues with :not */

$( document.querySelectorAll('#para input:not(input[optional])') )
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding the image tags with the no alt attribute or empty alt tag.

```
$('img').each(function( index ) {
    if(typeof $(this).attr('alt') === typeof undefined || $(this).attr('alt') === false ||$(this).attr('alt') === '') {
        console.log(index);
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.