# Get all the td which does not have colspan attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i am tryng to get all the td from each row in which colspan attribute is not defined

```
$('tr').each(function () {
   $(this).find('td').each(function () {
     if (($(this).text().trim() == ""))  && // and this td not has colspan attribute {
       $(this).closest("td").remove();
       };
    });
 });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the elements without a particular attribute by jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073779/how-can-i-get-the-elements-without-a-particular-attribute-by-jquery)

Comment: are you trying to remove same td or prev td ????

Comment: i need to remove same td

Comment: well check my answer, i think you can do that in one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per OP comment, he want to remove the `td` with `no colspan` and `empty` value. i guess this can be done that in one line. try this

```
$('td:empty:not([colspan])').remove();
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/F92De/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').each(function () {
   $(this).find('td').each(function () {
     if (($(this).text().trim() == ""))  && !$(this).attr('colspan') {
       $(this).closest("td").remove();
       };
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').each(function () {
   $(this).find('td:not([colspan])').each(function () {
     if (($(this).text().trim() == "")) {
       $(this).closest("td").remove();
       };
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you found that how many td are

```
$.each($('.tbody tr'), function() {
    var td1 = $(this).find('td');
    if(td1.length >= 2) {
        var orders = td1.eq(1).html().trim();

    }
});
```